# Paypal in context checkout - prevent page redirection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, paypal

I am trying to integrate PayPal [in-context checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/) under AngularJS app. Everything works as expected:

1. Via REST API I send all details and get checkout TOKEN
2. Then, TOKEN is passed to the client app
3. In-context checkout is called with certain TOKEN

Now I'm wondering **if there is a way to prevent redirecting the page** after either successful or cancelled scenario.

Here is the piece of code in client app:

```html
<button id="t2" type="submit">Pay</button>

<script>
  window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
    paypal.checkout.setup("API_CREDENTIALS", {
      environment: "sandbox",
      button: ["t2"],
      click: function (event) {
        
        event.preventDefault();
        //init lightbox modal
        paypal.checkout.initXO();
        
        //start checkout flow
        paypal.checkout.startFlow(TOKEN);
      }
    });
  };
</script>

<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async=""></script>
```

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your page. Is it possible for you to redirect the user back to the very same page they are on? (I've done this for social logins). If data gets lost in that process you might be able to store it in session cookies.

Comment: @zevnicsca Yes, it works with redirection now. My only request would be to avoid any kind of redirection - only because of one thing - user experience. So I need to know when the paypal script is done, and how it is done (success or error) and do the rest of routing with Angular.

Comment: Can you specify how you would control the user experience with Angular routing? Essentially the redirection is required with Express Checkout as you need to execute the payment within your return page, meaning the in-context pop-up experience is only providing user authorization/consent on the payment..

Comment: @pp_pduan That's what I am trying to hack. After the payment is done via in-context pop-up window, and the window is closed, redirection happens.I am trying prevent the page from redirecting. Via webhooks I will know the payment status, and depending on that I will redirect user via Angular routing to specific state. So, user should have such experience he is on the same page all the time...

Comment: There's a sequence here, 1. In-context pop-up and user interaction 2.Pop up auto close and redirection to your desinated return page 3. Call execute API in your return page to complete the payment 4. webhooks are triggered.  It makes little sense to hack step 2-3, plus there're ways you can carry over custom values route your customers to different return pages either with different URL or appending string queries...  I'll post the details in answer if you need, but just want to make sure you got the process right for In-Context checkout

Comment: @pp_pduan Ok, as this resolve my question as not possible, please write this through answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS based In-Context pop-up simply provides a front-end experience, and makes part of the payment sequence as outlined below,

1. In-context pop-up and user interaction (giving consent on payment)
2. Pop-up auto closed (controled by `checkout.js`, instantly) and browser redirection to your desinated return page
3. Call `execute` API in your return page to complete the payment
4. Webhooks are triggered (to notify your website about the transaction status)

What you're trying to interrupt is the behavior in between #2 and #3, which is in the middle of the payment flow, the customization you may look into is defining your `redirect_urls` object in the API payload of `PAY` method (which you use to generate payment Tokens), using `return_url` with your routing logic (by combination of URL and string queries) to display corresponding contents to your customers on the order confirmation page (Step#3)

Same rule in `cancel_url` when your customers cancel/close the pop-up window (Step#2)

```
"redirect_urls": {
 "return_url": "http://www.return.com/routing/?stringQuery",
 "cancel_url": "http://www.cancel.com/routing/?stringQuery"
}
```

*Just be sure to invoke the `execute` call in your return page afterward*